# Intellij: How to indent 2 spaces of next line from beginning of the previous line?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

[image]

The current indentation looks like this for the case class Foo but I'd like the indent for `a` and `b` to be 2 spaces indented from the beginning of the previous line like so

```
case class Foo(
  a: Int,
  b: Int
)
```

Is this possible? Where in the settings for Intellij is that?

Comment: Have you checked the other tabs spaces, wrapping, blank lines and all?

Comment: @RamanMishra yes

Comment: One important comment, continuation lines like what you mention should have 4 spaces not 2. This is to make a difference between the arguments of a method and it's body, so it should look like this:
```scala
case class Foo(
    a: Int,
    b: Int
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change following preferences in IntelliJ. Uncheck the one pointed by red arrow (`Align when multiline`) and check the one pointed by green (`Use normal indent for parameters`).

Now idea will use "normal indent" for parameters, so you need to check what your normal indent scheme is.

[image]